# how to setup mysql to work with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a working site on a remote server where my database is already setup.
Now I want to start a database of my own on my own server and run the site from there. I have downloaded mysql and installed it. I have created the same tables that I had on the remote server. I allowed the mysqli and mysql commands in php.ini. I do have a database named crom, but how do I connect to it?

Here are the commands that I used on the remote server(where I had my files uploaded).

```
$server="localhost";
$username='crom@localhost';
$password='ncrisnowredhorse';
$database="crom";

mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die("Problem connecting to the server");
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Problem connecting to the database");
```

Comment: Did you even try to search for this? simply google searching "mysqli" will give you everything you know. "pdo" as well. Don't use mysql_ functions though. That's deprecated

Comment: Yes I tried too look up some manual. This script worked for me on the remote server, so I wanted to use it on my own machine. However when I try to include the php file that is connecting to the DB and extracts values (this file) then only blank white page appears instead. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. (except now I know I should not use mysql anymore)

Comment: Probley the remote and your local are different with user i guess, Try to connect with mysql on command line or phpmyadmin. Also check if the port is 3306(that is the default)

Comment: The port is open.
I tried to extract errors to see what is wrong and I get this: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\apache\htdocs\Crom\includes\common.php on line 12

However I have allowed php_myqsl.dll and php_mysqli.dll extensions in the php.ini file so I don't understand why it should be an undefined function.

Comment: mysql database is not the problem, in case that was not clear. See perry's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please use or mysqli or PDO, because mysql is a old connection method.

Here is a example of a PDO connection:

```
try {
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=crom';
$username = 'crom@localhost'; //it can be root or just crom
$password = 'ncrisnowredhorse';
$options = array(
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Something went wrong'. $e->getMessage();
}
```